# Where are all the places where an environment variable can be set in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I had installed Hortonworks ambari, and now I want it completely removed from my system. I have uninstalled and cleaned deleted all related folders.

However I can still see that the environment variables are still pointing the old (unexisting) folder locations. I want to clean these environment variables, but unable in doing so.

I have checked in *~/.bashrc, /etc/profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/profile.d/** without luck.

Any other places where the environment variables could be set. I know I can unset them in my profiles, but I want them not to even get set.

Edit: I had also checked in */etc/environment*

Comment: use `grep -rl VARNAME /etc $HOME`

Comment: Check in `/etc/environment` too..

Comment: @heemayl - `grep -r ... /etc` does that!!

Comment: You can add it on ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile. Because everytime when you restart that user then it will reload. As well, after adding variables in this file you need to reload it with . ~/.profile or . ~/.bash_profile then you can get varaibles.

Comment: @StephenC yeah..i did not see Basile's comment :)

Comment: Flagged this for migration to unix.SE, since this doesn't belong here.  It might drop a file somewhere that sets an  env var for your whole desktop session when you log in (an X or kde/gnome thing), or for your session on *any* login if it's really silly.  (pam_env, /etc/environment, or something?)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks bro, that did the trick. Kindly put that as answer, so it is useful for others too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented, use

```
grep -rl VARNAME /etc $HOME
```

to ask [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) to *recursively* (`-r` search in file trees recursively) search and *list* filenames (`-l` ask `grep` to just list matching filenames) containing the pattern `VARNAME` inside `/etc` (the system-wide configuration directory) and inside your `$HOME`